# gsutil error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gslib'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, gsutil

`gsutil` command (with or without arguments) is returning the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gslib'

How to solve that, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem running this command:

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

Documentation:
*Installing gsutil as part of the Google Cloud SDK*
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#linux

Comment: Your answer has no context. The solution depends on the operating system. Improve your answer to explain how you got into this problem and links to the correct documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Following worked for me :
reinstall gsutil based on whichever python you use:

`pip3 install gsutil`

if not try following steps :

1. Uninstall Google SDK https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/uninstall-cloud-sdk
2. Reinstall Google SDK https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install
3. pip install gsutil